# How to print first 5 lines of a sorted csv file?

Tags: python, csv, sorting

In the code below, I need to print out the first 5 lines from the CSV file "winners.csv" and I don't know how to do it. I just know that lines 4-5 will cause all lines in the csv file to print.

The code in question:

```
wins = open("winners.csv", "r")
csv1 = csv.reader(wins, delimiter=",")
sort = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline)
wins.close()
```

Comment: Your question is misleading. You don't need the first 5 lines of a file. `sorted()` always returns a list, so you simply need the first 5 elements of a list...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: It was linked to wrong duplicate — and can be closed again if it is a dup of some other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through all elements in `sort`, loop through first five.

```
wins = open("winners.csv", "r")
csv1 = csv.reader(wins, delimiter=",")
sort = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
for eachline in sort[:5]: # <----- note how sort is changed to sort[:5]
    print(eachline)
wins.close()
```

Not directly related to your question, just mentioning a good practice. It's recommended to open files using `with`. Exception handling, closing the file after reading is done etc. will be done for you and your code will be cleaner.

```
with open("winners.csv", "r") as wins:
    csv1 = csv.reader(wins, delimiter=",")
    sort = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    for eachline in sort[:5]:
        print(eachline)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `enumerate` function allows you get the value and index of an iterator.

So you can check how many lines you've printed and break out of the loop:

```py
with open('winners.csv', 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        print(line)
        if index >= 5:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use slicing and `with` (to ensure the file stream has closed):

```
import csv,operator
with open("winners.csv", "r") as wins:
  csv1 = csv.reader(wins, delimiter=",")
  sort = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
  for eachline in sort[:5]: 
    print(eachline)
```

Easiest with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('winners.csv').head(5)
```

Comment: The pandas solution is not equivalent because it doesn't sort...